# How to handle clear button in a controlled range picker - ant design

Tags: reactjs, components, antd, daterangepicker

Getting this error when trying to clear the controlled Ant-design Range filter.

> Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
> In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

Here is my code.

```
function Demo() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (props) => {
    const [start, end] = props;
    setStartDate(start);
    setEndDate(end);
  };

  return (
    <RangePicker
      format={"DD-MM-YYYY"}
      value={[startDate, endDate]}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

I am expecting it to show no dates when cleared. ( Empty Range Picker )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use an if else block inside handleChange function

When you clear the range picker, props is `null`.

You might be expecting it to be [`null`, `null`]

So this case should be handled separately as below.

```
 const handleChange = (props) => {
    if (props) {
      const [start, end] = props;
      setStartDate(start);
      setEndDate(end);
    } else {
      setStartDate(null);
      setEndDate(null);
    }
  };
```

Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-controlled-range-picker-l3v72g?file=/App.js) for the complete code snippet.